# MassTransit 4 Unit Test Consumer timeout

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, masstransit

I have successfully used this testing pattern with sagas in MT 3.5.7 but now in MT 4.0 and testing a consumer I am getting a timeout using the `InMemoryTestHarness` to test publication of a message from a consumer.

Single stepping via test debug I can see the consumer gets invoked correctly and it publishes its message. The consumer does nothing except receive the message and publish a new message.

But awaiting the `_harness.SubscribeHandler` for the published message is timing out.

For sake of brevity the code below has my container registrations and test data set up removed.

```
[TestFixture]
public class ConsumerTest
{
    InMemoryTestHarness _harness;
    ConsumerTestHarness<TCommandConsumer> _consumer
    ConsumeContext<ConsumerCompleted> _resultHandler;

    [OneTimeSetup]
    public async Task TaskSetup()
    {
      IContainer _container;
      //...container registrations and test data setup

      _harness = new InMemoryTestHarnes();
      _consumer = _harness.Consumer<TCommandConsumer>( () => _container.Resolve<TCommandConsumer>() );
      await _harness.Start();
      await _harness.InputQueueSendEndpoint.Send(new TCommand { Source = testdataSource, Topic = testdataTopic });
     _resultHandler = await _harness.SubscribeHandler<ConsumerCompleted>(); //Timeout here
    }
```

The command consumer (`TCommandConsumer`) successfully receives the command sent from `InputQueueSendEndpoint.Send` and it publishes its response (`ConsumerCompleted`) but I can't get that handled in the test fixture.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MassTransit 4, the in-memory message fabric behaves the same as RabbitMQ. Previously, the in-memory would publish every message to every endpoint, regardless of whether or not there was a binding for that message type. Now, if there is no binding, the message isn't delivered.

So you'll need to create another receive endpoint instead of using `SubscribeHandler<T>`, and use `Handled<T>` to check if the message was published and received.

OR, you can just use the `_consumer.Published.Select<T>.Any()` on the consumer test harness to see if it published the event, rather than checked if it was consumed.

Comment: Thanks for w/kend response! Now I have overridden `ConfigureInMemoryReceiveEndpoint` and added `_received = Handled<ConsumerCompleted>(configurator);` but I am still not getting something because when I `await _received` in the test I still get the timeout error.

Comment: Chris, thanks for pointing in the right direction, finally got this figured out with your help and also looking here https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/57b2e39b8ba61920120309b54bd915adbd4379c9/src/MassTransit.AzureServiceBusTransport.Tests/ReceiveEndpoint_Specs.cs.

Forgetting everything in my above comment. After starting the test harness I used the I used
`_harness.Host.ConnectReceiveEndPoint("testqueue", x =>
            {
                resultHandled = Handled<TestResult>(x);
            });`
and was then able to `var result = await resultHandled;` successfully.